# WScript.shell is not working with IIS 7.5 and Windows 7

Tags: iis, wsh

I have to run .vbs through classic asp. From past quite a few days, I am working on this, but still can't find a solution.
My code is as follows:

```
Set oWshShell = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'sCmd = "%systemroot%\sysnative\cmd.exe"
'oWshShell.run "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe", 1, TRUE 
'oWshShell.run("%comspec% /c "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sharedagents\print.vbs",1,TRUE)
'owshshell.run sCmd
Set oWshShell=Nothing
```

I tried all the methods that are commented out, but while executing the page, Browser/IIS hangs indefinitely. I have tried all sorts of variation to put in `oWshShell`, but still I am being able to put it through. I have checked permissions, Registry and all sorts other tweaks that can be possible.

Is it due 32-bit/64-bit issue or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it on Windows 7 64-bit, your following code must be changed:

from:

```
'oWshShell.run "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe", 1, TRUE
```

to:

```
'oWshShell.run "c:\windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe", 1, TRUE
```

Also, verify if the cmd is running under administrator rules

[Windows 7 x64: Execute a 64bit exe/script from a 32bit command prompt?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/5bfc1d5b-1162-495a-bc89-252de06e4baa/windows-7-x64-execute-a-64bit-exescript-from-a-32bit-command-prompt?forum=ITCG) may help you.

Comment: I have tried that too. Even then the IIS is hanging.   When I try to run any script too from oWshShell.Run, then also its not working.